Cannot install Ros Iron Irvini on Ubuntu
if I want to install Ros2 Iron Irvini on Ubuntu 22.04. I always get the following error:
samyroboter@SamyRoboter:~$ locale  # check for UTF-8

sudo apt update && sudo apt install locales
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

locale  # verify settings
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_DE:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
[sudo] Passwort für samyroboter: 
OK:1 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
OK:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease    
OK:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
OK:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
OK:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
Fehl:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:3404:200:237::2 80]
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
E: Das Depot »http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release« enthält keine Release-Datei.
N: Eine Aktualisierung von solch einem Depot kann nicht auf eine sichere Art durchgeführt werden, daher ist es standardmäßig deaktiviert.
N: Weitere Details zur Erzeugung von Paketdepots sowie zu deren Benutzerkonfiguration finden Sie in der Handbuchseite apt-secure(8).
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_DE:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

What can I do?

First Remove all your ros2 packages you have previously installed. To have a clean environment:
sudo apt-get purge ros-*

Then Remove any ROS repositories you have set: Then you need
A) Check which repository is set, if you have any:
sudo apt list --installed | grep ros

B) If you find a repository listed after issuing cmd above, just remove it:
sudo apt-add-repository --remove <repository_name>

Replace <repository_name> with the name of the ROS repository you want to remove.
Then execute an autoremove cmd:
sudo apt-get autoremove

This will remove any remaining ROS-related packages and dependencies that are no longer needed.
Ok finally you have a cleaned space to reinstall ros2 iron:
Reinstallation Procedure
SetUp source to accept packages from packages.ros.org
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'

Setup ROS2 keys:
sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl gnupg2 lsb-release
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -

Install ROS2 Iron
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ros-iron-desktop

Initialize rosdep:
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update

If you prefer you can follow their website documentation: https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html
If does not work try to copy and past the error on chatgpt. It should work!

you need to:
1 setup the sources list:
sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl gnupg2 lsb-release
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null

2-Install ros2
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ros-iron-irvin-desktop  # For the full desktop environment, adjust package name if only the base is needed

3- Setup the Environment on bashrc
echo "source /opt/ros/iron/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

4- Check if dependencies are setup:
rosdep update
rosdep install --from-paths /opt/ros/iron/share --ignore-src --rosdistro iron -y

5- Finally test (run random node) :
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker


Thank You, but it generates the same problem:

Thank You. But I have sill the same problems. Is there may be a special setting in Ubuntu I have to change, so that it is possible to install ROS.

it should work. I have ros2 iron installed in my ubuntu 22.04. I will submit new answer with commands you can try.
